# How to namespace constants inside anonymous class definitions?

Tags: ruby

When creating anonymous classes through `Class.new`, they don't seem to have their own namespace for constants:

```
klass1 = Class.new do
  FOO = "foo"
end

klass2 = Class.new do
  FOO = "bar"
end
```

This gives `warning: already initialized constant FOO` and looks like it's right:

```
> klass1.const_get(:FOO)
"bar"
> klass2.const_get(:FOO)
"bar"
> FOO
"bar"
```

I was going to use this approach in a simple DSL for defining addons for an application, something like this:

```
class App
  class AddonBase

    attr_reader :session

    def initialize(session)
      @session = session
    end
  end

  def self.addons
    @addons ||= {}
  end

  def self.addon(name, &block)
    addons[name] = Class.new(AddonBase, &block)
  end
end
```

This works fine for simple add-ons but if defining constants, they will be under `Object::` instead of becoming `addons[name]::CONSTANT`:

```
App.addon "addon1" do

  PATH="/var/run/foo"

  def execute
    File.touch(PATH)
  end
end

App.addon "addon2" do

  PATH="/etc/app/config"

  def execute
    File.unlink(PATH)
  end
end

# warning: already initialized constant PATH
```

The constants could be anything and the add-ons could even define their own utility subclasses, so it's not just about replacing `PATH` with a function.

Is there some way to work around this?

Comment: Presumably, looking at that code structure, all constants defined in `AddonBase` will have exactly one value? So would I be right in saying that the behaviour is fine, and really you just want to "suppress" the warning?

Comment: i.e. Could you just do something like: `class AddonBase; FOO = "bar" unless defined?(FOO); ...`?

Comment: How is your `AddonBase` code related to the other examples? You don't define any constants there.

Comment: @TomLord no, the problem is just that different addons should be able to define something like their own `CONFIG_PATH="/etc/foo.conf"`. Of course there could be instructions on how to define constants or to avoid them, but it would be super nice if this wasn't necessary and people could write them "as expected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When creating **anonymous** classes through Class.new, they don't seem to have their own **namespace** for constants

Sure, by the definition of the word “anonymous.” Compare two following snippets:

```
class C1; puts "|#{name}|"; end
#⇒ |C1|
C2 = Class.new { puts "|#{name}|" }
#⇒ ||
```

Unless assigned to the constant, the class has no name and hence all constants defined inside go to `Object` namespace. That said, the warning here is actually pointing out to error and `Object::FOO = "bar"` overrides `Object::FOO = "foo"` constant.

That said, one cannot use constants in this scenario. Use class-level instance variables instead, or construct unique constant names manually (I would advise avoiding polluting `Object` class with a bunch of unrelated constants, though.)

Comment: Assigning the class to a constant through `const_set` does not seem to give it a name. `Addons.const_set(klassify(name), Class.new(AddonBase, &block))`

Comment: Check `Addons::klassify(name).name` and you’ll see it has a name.

Comment: Not during the definition though.

Comment: During the definition, the constant is not yet declared. Ruby is the scripting language that is processed sequentially. 1) `Class.new` 2) `const_set`. One cannot expect everything is to be on hand at any time.

Comment: Yes, that's true, just clarifying that it does not solve the original problem, which is defining constants during `Class.new { block }`, but I marked this as the answer as it explains why it is not solvable.

Answer (score 4):

> When creating anonymous classes through `Class.new`, they don't seem to have their own namespace for constants

They do, you can use [`const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-const_set) to define constants in anonymous classes:

```
klass1 = Class.new do
  const_set(:FOO, 'foo')
end

klass2 = Class.new do
  const_set(:FOO, 'bar')
end

klass1::FOO #=> "foo"
klass2::FOO #=> "bar"
```

Or via `self::`

```
klass1 = Class.new do
  self::FOO = 'foo'
end

klass2 = Class.new do
  self::FOO = 'bar'
end

klass1::FOO #=> "foo"
klass2::FOO #=> "bar"
```

Comment: Hmm, I could use a regexp to replace anything that looks like a constant assignment to use `const_set` or `self::`.

Comment: @KimmoLehto regexp? Are you processing source code files / strings? Maybe you could provide a more complete example. I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is how to define a class using a proc including constant definitions. As has already been said it is not possible the way you did it, since the proc gets class_eval'd and that doesn't allow to define constants.

I suggest another approach. Can you use modules instead of procs to define new addons mixing a module into a class?

**Example:**

```
module AddonModule
  FOO = "foo"
end

klass = Class.new
klass.include AddonModule

klass::FOO # => "foo"
```

**Usage in your DSL:**

```
def self.addon(name, addon_module)
  addon = Class.new(AddonBase)
  addon.include addon_module

  addons[name] = addon
end
```

Comment: In that case I could just as well instruct the users to do `class FoofooAddon < AddonBase` and write a `self.inherited` hook into `AddonBase`. That is probably what I will end up doing unless someone finds out a way to do that via the friendlier DSL syntax.